# pure-ftpd installation error "E: Couldn't find package pure-ftpd error"

Tags: fedora, software-installation, pure-ftpd

I am trying to install `pure-ftpd` on my Fedora, but I'm getting this message:

```
E: Couldn't find package pure-ftpd"
```

Here is my full command line and the output:

```
[roo@localhost ~]$ sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd
[sudo] password for roo: 
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package pure-ftpd
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: you're using `apt-get` on a Fedora system? why?

Comment: Seems an extra hoop to jump through when there's dnf/yum/rpm

Comment: Since it's unusual to use `apt-get` on Fedora, it would be useful to know what sources you're pulling packages from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[apt-get](/questions/tagged/apt-get) method uses in Debian-based distributions. In Fedora you can use [yum](/questions/tagged/yum) or [dnf](/questions/tagged/dnf).

Try it:

```
dnf install pure-ftpd
```

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Differences_to_Ubuntu#Using_apt_anyway

Comment: @JeffSchaller, yes, I know it.